# How can I replace some text in html on python?

Tags: html, python-3.x, replace

My situation is...
I have few hundreds of chrome html files on one folder, and I want to replace certain text(ex. james) to another text(ex. tom) for every html files. Honestly, I'm just a beginner to python, so may I get a detailed code of it? I need 1. how to open every html file in one folder 2. how to find certain text on html 3. how to replace it to another text (on python) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can just open up the directory in VSC and bulk replace all the instances of any string in all the HTML files directly. I required to do the same and found this to be a very convenient method.
[image]